# "zeved habat" or simkhat habat

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, minhag

Is there any mention in jewish law about "zeved habat"or shimkhat habat??

And what are the things to be done according to the law?

Also is it necessary to do this zevad habat if it cross many years?

Comment: answered here? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70042/1362

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73206/170

Answer (score 0):

As [discussed previously](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70042/1362), many have a nice custom to do some sort of celebration -- as you'll see there, usually it involves saying some Psalms or verses from Song of Songs, offering a blessing, maybe saying *shehechiyanu* (thanking God on a momentous occasion), and naming the girl if that hadn't already happened -- you'll find versions of it some 21st Century siddurim (I believe Koren-Sacks and the very newest Artscroll RCA), but it's hard to call it an all-out obligation. If it didn't happen for more than a year ... I suppose someone could still do one if they really wanted, but it's really their call.

Rabbi Hershel Schachter's recent [Corona responsum #11](https://www.yutorah.org/_cdn/public/v3/js/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=https://content.yutorah.org/viewer/2020/1053/950292.pdf) says if the synagogues are closed due to a pandemic, the family should just name the baby girl at home, rather than wait for the synagogues to re-open.

In normal circumstances, it would be very common for the parents to sponsor *kiddush* at synagogue a few weeks after the baby is born, though I've seen those get delayed by many months -- the point is the family is publicly showing their thanks; the story is told of the parents of a 20-year-old lady who was having some problems in life; the rabbi (R. Yaakov Kaminetsky, I think) inquired whether they ever held a kiddush in her honor and they said no, so he told them to do one then.

Long story short -- these are nice customs if you feel like it, but there's a tremendous amount of leeway.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48910/759